# Type * error in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When I run my code I get the following error for all the statements that have the following format. Is there any problem with the type statement? If yes kindly provide me with a solution. I running my code on a Ubuntu 14.10 system. The program is very long hence I am not posting it now however if required I can surely send it.

recfunk_ascii.f:622.12:

```
  type *,'enter back-azimuth limits ib1,ib2 (integers!)'            
        1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the type statement?

Comment: @Ross Probably what would now be `print`.

Comment: For the record that is a language extension  accepted by some compilers.  You might also see `accept` which should be replaced with `read`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type is an obsolete and completely non-standard statement (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnbi/index.html). It is not portable because many compilers do not recognize it. It should be changed to a  `PRINT` statement, as @francescalus suggest in the comment.

```
print *,'enter back-azimuth limits ib1,ib2 (integers!)'
```

Comment: The link is broken for me.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing the "type" statement with "print" solved the problem